# Selecting values from one dataframe if dates matches other dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, if df1$date1 matches df2$date2 then print only those values from df2 as shown in the output.

```
df1:

date1
01-09-2018
01-10-2018
01-11-2018
01-12-2018

df2:

date2       value
01-05-2018      0
01-06-2018      0
01-07-2018      0
01-08-2018      0
01-09-2018      5
01-10-2018      2
01-11-2018      7
01-12-2018      3

output:

value
5
2
7
3
```

Comment: `df2$value[match(df1$date1, df2$date2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `merge` here in inner join mode:

```
merge(df2, df1, by="date", all=FALSE)$value
[1] 5 2 7 3

# data
df2 <- data.frame(date=c("01-05-2018", "01-06-2018", "01-07-2018", "01-08-2018",
                         "01-09-2018","01-10-2018","01-11-2018","01-12-2018"),
                  value=c(0,0,0,0,5,2,7,3))
df1 <- data.frame(date=c("01-09-2018", "01-10-2018", "01-11-2018", "01-12-2018"))
```

### Demo

Note that I renamed your date columns both to `date`, which is needed for `merge` to easily work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`: We can perform `inner join` between two `data.frames` using `date` column

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.value from df2 as a JOIN df1 USING(date)")
```

Output:

```
   value
1     5
2     2
3     7
4     3
```

Data (provided by Tim):

```
df2 <- data.frame(date=c("01-05-2018", "01-06-2018", "01-07-2018", "01-08-2018",
                 "01-09-2018","01-10-2018","01-11-2018","01-12-2018"),
                 value=c(0,0,0,0,5,2,7,3))
df1 <- data.frame(date=c("01-09-2018", "01-10-2018", "01-11-2018", "01-12-2018"))
```